# How to create a response using node.js fulfillment on hangouts chat showing an image?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, google-hangouts

I need to use my bot to show an image.
This image can change according to the value of a parameter.
I will make it with the node.js inline editor fullfillment.
My bot will be integrated with google hangouts chat.

Firstly, i try to show my image using this code :

I want to do it:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

function image(agent){
      agent.add(
        new Card({
         title: `this is my image`,
         imageUrl: 'image/url.jpg'
       }
    )
  )
}

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('test_image', image);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
  }
);
```

but this only works when I test it in the console.
Whe i try with hangouts chats i can see the error :

```
Error: No responses defined for platform: hangouts
```

I have seen that i could create a function like this one

```
function buildImageCard(url) {
  return {
    cards: [
      {
        sections: [
          {
            widgets: [
              {
                image: {
                  imageUrl: url
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

but i can't succeed in using it well in my function "image".

Do you have any idea that could help me ?